# Pattern for returning next value?

Tags: java, design-patterns, iteration

I have a java class which generates Strings. Now I thought I don't want to return an array of string but only one string per call with a "getNextString" method.
Then one can call the method in a loop like that:

```
while(abc.getNextString() != null) {
    ...
}
```

I have seen this a few times in java I guess but now I wonder if there is a pattern or a best practice for methods like that?
The method depends on start values so where should I initialise them?
What happend if the initialise method is called by another peace of code before all strings are returned?

Whould be nice to see something about that! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern is called the `Iterator` pattern. You probably want your class to `implements Iterable<String>`; it will then be required to implement a method that returns an `Iterator<String>`.

The `Iterator<String>` is a single use iterator, so the initialisation would happen when you constructed the `Iterator<String>`.

The `Iterator<T>` interface has a slightly nicer api than checking for null, so you do:

```
while(myIterator.hasNext()) {
    final String myString = myIterator.next();
}
```

And if you implement `Iterable<String>` then the enhanced for-each loop will actually call the `iterator()` method and construct the loop for you, so that the loop becomes

```
for(final String myString : abc) {
}
```

The idea is that each iterator is independent and therefore you cannot have problems with the init method being called out of order.

Also, you could, in theory, have multiple threads all walking along their own iterators and that wouldn't pose problems either.

Having your `Collection` class be an `Iterator` itself is a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

This would be the Iterator that you should implement. The iterator maintains its current position. There should be no initialize() method. Instead, you construct the Iterator in the Iterable and make sure using visibility (private, package private) that the iterator cannot be tampered with. If the Iterable, however, can be edited concurrently you could maintain a version counter with the Iterable, let the Iterator check against the counter whether it changed and throw a ConcurrentModificationException if so.

Answer (score 0):

You need two things to make this work:

- a string generator that generates a string from a string,
- your own datastructure that will remember the last generated string.

Something like:

```
public class StringGenerator {

    private String lastString;

    public StringGenerator() {
        this(null);
    }

    public StringGenerator(String startString) {
         lastString= startString;
    }

    public String getNextString() {
        if (lastString == null) {
            lastString= UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        }
        lastString= generateString(lastString);
        return lastString;
    }

    //private string generator (find any on the internet)
    private String generateString(String str) {
        .... maybe use md5 hash
    }
}
```